# How can I click on all links matching a selector with Playwright?

Tags: javascript, playwright

I'm using Playwright to scrape some data. How do I click on all links on the page matching a selector?

```
const { firefox } = require('playwright');

(async () => {
  const browser = await firefox.launch({headless: false, slowMo: 50});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  
  await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
  
  page.pause(); // allow user to manually search for something
  
  const wut = await page.$$eval('a', links => {
    links.forEach(async (link) => {
      link.click();           // maybe works?
      console.log('whoopee'); // doesn't print anything
      page.goBack();          // crashes
    });
    return links;
  });

  console.log(`wut? ${wut}`); // prints 'wut? undefined'

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Some issues:

1. `console.log` inside the `$$eval` doesn't do anything.
2. `page.goBack()` and `page.pause()` inside the eval cause a crash.
3. The return value of `$$eval` is `undefined` (if I comment out `page.goBack()` so I get a return value at all). If I return `links.length` instead of `links`, it's correct (i.e. it's a positive integer). Huh?

I get similar results with:

```
const links = await page.locator('a');
await links.evaluateAll(...)
```

Clearly I don't know what I'm doing. What's the correct code to achieve something like this?

([X-Y problem alert](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): I don't actually care if I do this with `$$eval`, `Playwright`, or frankly even Javascript; all I really want to do is make this work in *any* language or tool).

Comment: Remember that the function you pass to `$$eval` runs inside the browser. So the `console.log` will be printed in the browser and `page.goBack` won't work inside the browser.

Comment: @hardkoded - Thank you, that explains why I'm missing the logging. I can perhaps return an array of strings for that. But if `page.goBack()` doesn't work, how can I get back to the original page? (Or does each link open in a new page/browser?)

Comment: Exactly. You can't keep the elements across navigations. You need to keep your elements in some way you can query them again. That could me as simple as keeping the index, if you trust that the links won't change across navigations.

Comment: Let me be sure I understand here: when I do `link.click()`, the browser navigates to a new page. There's no way to get a reference to the new page? No way to find an element, click a link on it, nothing? What good is `link.click()` then?

Answer (score 6):

```
const { context } = await launch({ slowMo: 250 });
const page = await context.newPage();
await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70702820/how-can-i-click-on-all-links-matching-a-selector-with-playwright');

const links = page.locator('a:visible');
const linksCount = await links.count();

for (let i = 0; i < linksCount; i++) {
  await page.bringToFront();

  try {
    const [newPage] = await Promise.all([
      context.waitForEvent('page', { timeout: 5000 }),
      links.nth(i).click({ modifiers: ['Control', 'Shift'] })
    ]);
    await newPage.waitForLoadState();
    console.log('Title:', await newPage.title());
    console.log('URL: ', page.url());

    await newPage.close();
  }
  catch {
    continue;
  }
}
```

There's a number of ways you could do this, but I like this approach the most. Clicking a link, waiting for the page to load, and then going back to the previous page has a lot of problems with it - most importantly is that for many pages the links might change every time the page loads. Ctrl+shift+clicking opens in a new tab, which you can access using the [Promise.all pattern and catching the 'page' event](https://playwright.dev/docs/pages#handling-new-pages).

I only tried this on *this* page, so I'm sure there's tons of other problems that my arise. But for this page in particular, using 'a:visible' was necessary to prevent getting stuck on hidden links. The whole clicking operation is wrapped in a try/catch because some of the links aren't real links and don't open a new page.

Depending on your use case, it may be easiest just to grab all the hrefs from each link:

```
const links = page.locator('a:visible');
const linksCount = await links.count();

const hrefs = [];
for (let i = 0; i < linksCount; i++) {
  hrefs.push(await links.nth(i).getAttribute('href'));
}

console.log(hrefs);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach.I will use typescript.

```
await page.waitForSelector(selector,{timeout:10000});
const links = await page.$$(selector);

for(const link of links)
{
   await link.click({timeout:8000});
   //your additional code
}
```

See more on https://youtu.be/54OwsiRa_eE?t=488