# Get href link using python playwright

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, playwright, playwright-python

I am trying to extract the link inside a href but all I am finding it is the text inside the element

The website code is the following:

```html
<div class="item-info-container ">
   <a href="/imovel/32600863/" role="heading" aria-level="2" class="item-link xh-highlight" 
   title="Apartamento T3 na avenida da Liberdade, São José de São Lázaro e São João do Souto, Braga">
   Apartamento T3 na avenida da Liberdade, São José de São Lázaro e São João do Souto, Braga
   </a>
```

And the code I am using is:

```
element_handle = page.locator('//div[@class="item-info-container "]//a').all_inner_texts()
```

No matter if I specify `//a[@href]` or not, my output is always the title text:

```
Apartamento T3 na avenida da Liberdade, São José de São Lázaro e São João do Souto, Braga
```

When what I really want to achieve is:

```
/imovel/32600863/
```

Any ideas of where my logic is failing me?

Comment: The ELEMENT you want is the `<a>` element.  Once you have that element, you need to use `get_attribute` to fetch its `href` attribute.  Playwright was not designed for web scraping.  Why are you using it?  There are several packages that were designed specifically for scraping.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I use playwright because it is the only one I was able to bypass DataDome with

Comment: See this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/70750943

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `get_attribute`:

```py
link = page.locator('.item-info-container ').get_by_role('link').get_attribute('href')
```

More than one locator:

```py
link_locators = page.locator('.item-info-container ').get_by_role('link').all()
for _ in link_locators:
    print(_.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: Code returns an error playwright._impl._api_types.Error: Error: strict mode violation: locator(".item-info-container").get_by_role("link") resolved to 30 elements:

Comment: Added code if more than one

Comment: Just saw that you sorted it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Managed to do it by finding all elements and then getting the attribute after handling all elements.

```
handleLinks = page.locator('//div[@class="item-info-container "]/a')
    for links in handleLinks.element_handles():
        linkF = links.get_attribute('href')
        print(linkF)
```

and the outcome would be:

```
/imovel/32611494/
/imovel/32642523/
/imovel/32633771/
/imovel/32527162/
/imovel/30344934/
/imovel/31221488/
/imovel/32477875/
/imovel/31221480/
/imovel/32450120/
/imovel/32515628/
/imovel/32299064/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just omit the `//` and use the following XPath-1.0 expression:

```
//div[@class="item-info-container "]/a/@href
```

This will give you the `@href` attribute's value: "/imovel/32600863/".
Probably the whole command will be

```
element_handle = page.locator('//div[@class="item-info-container "]/a/@href').all_inner_texts()
```

but the result of the expression is not an element, but an attribute, so this may fail.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76626222/6243352) is optimal for getting the href from a single element, but an alternative approach for grabbing multiple href attributes is to use `evaluate_all` rather than use element handles. `.all()` is discouraged, since each subsequent `.get_attribute()` call will be a new inter-process network request on a handle that might be stale. In contrast, `evaluate_all` only does one network request to the browser, using synchronous JavaScript to extract all data in one shot.

Here's an example:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright # 1.40.0


html = """<div class="item-info-container ">
<a href="/imovel/32600863/" role="heading" aria-level="2" class="item-link xh-highlight" title="Apartamento T3 ...">
  Apartamento T3 ...
</a></div>"""

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.set_content(html)
    links = (
        page.locator(".item-info-container a")
            .evaluate_all("els => els.map(el => el.href)")
    )
    print(links)
    browser.close()
```

I generally suggest avoiding XPath when CSS selectors suffice; the syntax is much cleaner.