# Obtain href links from first table in headless browser page (playwright._impl._errors.Error: Event loop is closed! Is Playwright already stopped?)

Tags: python, href, playwright, playwright-python

I am trying to get the href links from the first table of a headless browser page but the error isn't helping me as it's not telling me what it is, just lots of ^ symbols underneath.

I had to switch to a headless browser because I was scraping empty tables for how the site's HTML works and I admit I don't understand how it works.

I also want to complete the links so that they work for further use, which is the last three lines of the following code:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

# headless browser to scrape
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/Premier-League-Stats")

#open the file up
with open("path", 'r') as f:
    file = f.read()

years = list(range(2024,2022, -1))

all_matches = []

standings_url = "https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/Premier-League-Stats"

for year in years:
    standings_table = page.locator("table.stats_table").first

    link_locators = standings_table.get_by_role("link").all()
    for l in link_locators:
        l.get_attribute("href")
    print(link_locators)

    link_locators = [l for l in links if "/squads/" in l]
    team_urls = [f"https://fbref.com{l}" for l in link_locators]
    print(team_urls)

browser.close()
```

The stack trace I get is just:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path", line 27, in <module>
    link_locators = standings_table.get_by_role("link").all()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "path\.venv\Lib\site-packages\playwright\sync_api\_generated.py", line 15936, in all
    return mapping.from_impl_list(self._sync(self._impl_obj.all()))
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "path\.venv\Lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_sync_base.py", line 102, in _sync
    raise Error("Event loop is closed! Is Playwright already stopped?")
playwright._impl._errors.Error: Event loop is closed! Is Playwright already stopped?

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My code is only 33 lines as it's the start of a loop, so I'm unsure what the last two errors in the stack refer to.

I just can't extract the href links. It might have to do with `.first`.

I implemented the solution from [Get href link using python playwright](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76624911/get-href-link-using-python-playwright) but it doesn't work.

Comment: What's `file = f.read()` and what is your expected output? Surely, there's more to the traceback. Try running the code again and copy the whole stack trace, please. You create `soup` but never use it--why?

Comment: Apologies, I was previously using BeautifulSoup to parse but had to switch to a headless browser so switched to Playwright, I edited the post to reflect that. `with open("path", 'r') as f:  file = f.read()` is there to read the headless browser

Comment: `file` is unused; there's no need to "read" a headless browser Anyway, all of your `browser` and `page` code needs to be inside the `with` block that launches Playwright, as the error message says. See ["Event loop is closed! Is Playwright already stopped?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77134706/event-loop-is-closed-is-playwright-already-stopped)

Answer (score 1):

When the context manager (`with`) block ends, the page and browser are closed, so you can't use them outside the block. A minimal reproduction of the error is:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright # 1.40.0


with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()

browser.close()
```

Here's a rewrite suggestion:

```py
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    url = "<Your URL>"
    page.goto(url, wait_until="domcontentloaded")
    team_urls = []

    for year in range(2024, 2022, -1):
        standings_table = page.locator("table.stats_table").first

        for x in standings_table.get_by_role("link").all():
            href = x.get_attribute("href")

            if "/squads/" in href:
                team_urls.append(f'https://www.fbref.com{href}')

    print(team_urls)
    browser.close()
```

Blocking resources can help speed things up a bit:

```py
# ...
    def handle(route, request):
        block = "image", "script", "xhr", "fetch"
        if request.resource_type in block:
            return route.abort()

        route.continue_()

    page.route("**", handle)
    page.goto(url, wait_until="domcontentloaded")
# ...
```

But you can also do this more simply and efficiently without Playwright, since the data is available in the static HTML:

```py
import requests # 2.25.1
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # 4.10.0


url = "<Your URL>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "lxml")
team_urls = []

for year in range(2024, 2022, -1):
    standings_table = soup.select_one("table.stats_table")

    for x in standings_table.select("a"):
        href = x["href"]

        if "/squads/" in href:
            team_urls.append(f'https://www.fbref.com{href}')

print(team_urls)
```

Benchmark:

Playwright (with blocked resources):

```
real 0m4.875s
user 0m1.331s
sys  0m0.250s
```

Requests/BS:

```
real 0m0.517s
user 0m0.376s
sys  0m0.029s
```